# Possibility to work with google maps from linux bash terminal

Tags: bash, google-maps, terminal

My intention is to use terminal as main access point for managing google maps.

For example, i have a list of ip addresses in a file. i could do something like this

cat ip.list | getlatlang | displayonmap

after this, ip addresses are translated to coordinates and fed into my script that opens google maps window with these points marked so i can see the big picture..

Is there any way to achieve this? I have an idea of using it with google maps embedded into website and javascript as the one, that will perform all the api calls. However much better would be a way to actually access google maps application on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL hash to pass arguments to a webpage, and in the webpage continue with the Google Maps JavaScript API.

For example, you can use bash to write the coordinates to coords.txt, and then run

```
firefox my_map_page.html#coords.txt
```

In the `onload` event of `my_map_page.html`, you can call use `location.hash` to get the part after the `#` - that is, `coords.txt`, and than open the file, read the coords from there, and display them on the map with the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

If the coord list is short enough, you can pass it directly in the URL hash.

Comment: Thank you for idea. By using file i could solve problem of url limit.